# Python: taking command output and putting into dictionary while also removing character

Tags: python, linux, dictionary

I'm creating a dictionary from the output of a command I'm running in Linux.

```
import sys, subprocess, os, string

mycmd = '/usr/bin/mycmd'

myDict = {}

def make_dict(cmd=mycmd):
   get_list_cmd = subprocess.Popen('{cmd} get list'.format(cmd=cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, err = get_list_cmd.communicate()
   for i in output.splitlines():
      detail=i.split(":")
      myDict[detail[0].strip()]=detail[1].strip()

make_dict()
```

When I run this I get the following error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.
Below is the output of the command when I use `print(output.split())` without trying to put it into a dictionary:

```
[b'Serial#', b':', b'xxx00', b'LV', b':',
b'0', b'SL', b':', b'0', b'CL', b':', b'0', 
etc..]
```

How can I remove the `'b'` before every item?

Comment: Try using `.decode('utf8')`  at the string at the location you get the error. In your case `output = [x.decode('utf8') for x in output]`.

Comment: I've tried adding `output = [x.decode('utf8') for x in output]
   print(output.split())` to my code but now I get the error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Hmm, then you can try
`output = [x.decode('utf8') if type(x) == bytes else x for x in output]`.

Comment: When I print `output` it is all integers now `[83, 101, 114, 105, 97, 108, 35, 32, 32, 58, 32, 52, 52...]`

Comment: Well, if it is all integers, then you don't need to `decode` anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you have a `list` like this:

```
a = [b'Serial#', b':', b'xxx00', b'LV', b':',b'0', b'SL', b':', b'0', b'CL', b':', b'0']
```

You need to decode it, for example, to `utf8`:

```
c = [k.decode("utf8") for k in a]
```

Output:

```
print(c)
>>> ['Serial#', ':', 'xxx00', 'LV', ':', '0', 'SL', ':', '0', 'CL', ':', '0']
```

Comment: `mylist = (output.split())`
   `test = [k.decode("utf8") for k in mylist]`
   `print(test)`
**This worked for me**

Comment: Yes, you have to work out with your code. I just gave you an example of how to dot it. Happy code.